# No code completion in dockerised Java application

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea

I am working with a Spring-boot application using IntelliJ. I am trying to get it running in Docker and have got it building and running fine in a container.  My problem is that the IDE cannot see the JDK in the container and so does not index my classes. This means I have no code completion in IntelliJ.

I could install a local JDK and point IntelliJ at that, but it seems like a bad idea to be using two JDKs. I would prefer all the dependencies to be in Docker so that I and other developers have only one configuration and don’t have to locally install anything other than Docker to develop, build, and run it.

Comment: You're running IntelliJ on the local machine but want it to use the JDK installed on the container? That seems more than weird, of course you install the JDK you need on the machine you're running your IDE. Is the container even running while you're using IntelliJ?

Comment: Hi! If I understand you correctly, you need the functionality described in [this feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-194266) in YouTrack. Please, feel free to upvote it to show your interest.